# Read data embedded in pptx chart

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'd like to use the python-pptx library to read the embedded data sheet behind a chart inside a presentation. I've seen the documentation to replace chart data, but I can't figure out how to read data.
I've already referred to [Read chart data from existing chart using python-pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818347/read-chart-data-from-existing-chart-using-python-pptx) but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`chart.part.chart_workbook.xlsx_part.blob` will give you the Excel binary (bytes).

From there you can save that as a file or read it as an in-memory file using `io.BytesIO()`, or whatever suits your purposes.

You could, for example, open it with `openpyxl` and read and write the Excel "file".

Comment: Okay so I've been able to read data to an extent: `prs = Presentation(presentation_path)
graphic_frame = prs.slides[2].shapes
chart = graphic_frame[0].chart

plot = chart.plots[0]
category_labels = [c.label for c in plot.categories]
series = plot.series[0]

md = {}
for i in range(0,len(plot.series)):
    md[plot.series[i].name] = list(plot.series[i].values)

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = [c.label for c in plot.categories]

for key, value in md.items():
    chart_data.add_series(key, [10*v for v in value])

chart.replace_data(chart_data)
`

Comment: Would you say that accessing the slide>shape>graphic_frame>plot>series is one way of doing it?

Comment: @scanny my purpose is that I have bunch of ppt files from anywhere, besides the text content, I want to extract the charts and tables from files `as images`. prefer treat them as `images` because I'm not expecting a library (like `pptx`) can extract the text content from complicated chart and table perfectly, so is there any API in pptx I can call to detect the area of chart and table in a slide and then `crop this area out` to save as images for further processing?